# Java Regex - correct the pattern

Tags: java, regex

Pattern - `<(\w+)>.+</\1>`

Input String - `"Testing <tag>some <b>idiot</b> text</tag>idiot text continue.."`

Now I received the result as `"<tag>some <b>idiot</b> text</tag>"`. Is there any way I can modify the pattern, so that it will give me result something like :

```
"<tag>some <b>idiot</b> text</tag>"
"<b>idiot</b>"
```

Comment: show some inputs and what you like to match

Comment: Please use a parser for that.

Comment: Possibly, yes--but if the tags can be nested arbitrarily deeply you might be better off not implementing that part as a regex, but as a recursive function on the results. Or use an HTML parser.

Comment: Some folks are a little quick on the downvote--feel free to take the time to edit to see if the question was just poorly-escaped rather than a fundamentally unsound question.

Comment: is something wrong with question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<(\\w+)>.+</\\1>");
String input = "Testing <tag>some <b>idiot</b> text</tag>idiot text continue..";
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

for (int i = 0; m.find(i); i = m.start() + 1)
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

**Output:**

```
<tag>some <b>idiot</b> text</tag>
<b>idiot</b>
```